# Error around package files for Node.js Discord bot

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, discord, discord.js

I have a basic Discord bot I am trying to publish through Heroku because I can't host it locally anymore.
Should mention that it runs perfectly fine when hosted locally on my VM.
When trying to push to Heroku through cli or git I am getting an error which says:

> npm ERR! cipm can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
> remote:        npm ERR!
> remote:        npm ERR!
> remote:        npm ERR! Missing: enmap@^5.2.4
> remote:        npm ERR! Missing: eslint@^7.2.0

Tried googling and and still have no idea how these package files work, so would be grateful if someone could tell me what to change.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "sidbot2",
  "version": "2.3.2",
  "description": "",
  "main": "sidbot.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "sidilleth",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^12.2.0",
    "enmap": "^5.2.4"
    "eslint": "^7.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: I should also mention I have run the npm install command like it suggested but i still get the error

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add all your code in the question itself and read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I haven't included the code in the question because its insanely long, and theres no 'take bits out until it does work' as all data in package files is required?  cant really make my issue any clearer?

Comment: I suggest you edit your question and add content of `package.json` in question. `package-lock.json` is not really required, you can remove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `eslint` from `dependencies` as it is already present in the `dev dependencies`. It should look similar to this:

```
{
  "name": "sidbot2",
  "version": "2.3.2",
  "description": "",
  "main": "sidbot.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "sidilleth",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^12.2.0",
    "enmap": "^5.2.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.2.0"
  }
}
```

Delete `node_modules` folder and execute `npm install`.

Also make sure that the all the changes made in `package.json` and `package-lock.json` has been committed to git.