# Heroku failed to push

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I want to deploy my project on Heroku but when I do it, I have this error :

```
       npm ERR! cipm can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's fs@0.0.1-security does not satisfy fs@*
       npm ERR! 
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.3oo5n/_logs/2021-11-25T14_47_03_365Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
```

Even when I delete "package-lock.json" and make "npm install", it still doesn't work.
This is the first time that I have this problem with Heroku deployment, I don't know what can I do about it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to run `npm install` _locally_, then commit the updated lock file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error around package files for Node.js Discord bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62732093/error-around-package-files-for-node-js-discord-bot)

Comment: Like I said, I ran "npm install" , when I do this, there is no difference between the first "package-lock" and the "updated" one...

Comment: Do you also have an `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file? That takes precedence over `package-lock.json` if present.

Comment: No, I've never used that

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and it was working at first then it stopped. Deleting the `packages-lock.json` file and then re-running `npm install` wasn't working. Strangely it did work if I just removed `packages-lock.json` but that wasn't the ideal solution.

Finally, I did get it to work by following:

1. delete my `packages-lock.json` file
2. delete `node_modules`
3. re-run `npm install`